# What can be the pole zero diagram

Tags: z-transform, homework, poles-zeros

Does the pole zero plot for $$H(z)=(1-z^{-1})^3(1+z^{-1})^3$$ have 6 poles at origin and 3 zeroes at 1? Just answer yes or no, not your homework question knowledge

Comment: You recently asked another homework question and was told to show your attempts and where you’re stuck in order to get help. Why would you think you wouldn’t be asked the same thing here?

Comment: **We are not HomeworkGPT!**.  Some of us might _help_ you with your homework, but we will not **do** your homework for you.  [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is about homework questions on the stackoverflow site, but much of it applies here.  Show your work, explain where you're stuck, expect that we'll try to help you _understand_, but it's your job to _actually do your homework_, etc.

Comment: same problem as your previous question. You just forward your homework to us, and think we'll write an answer. We won't. you need to **show** what you've done, what you've gotten, and you **must** ask a precise question to get further from where you are.

Comment: First of all If I could have started the answer I wouldn't have posted the question here (I can't publish my work if there isn't any). Second thing is I don't want you all to solve it, I just needed a yes or no. If you don't want to help comment somewhere else not here.

Comment: One factually correct answer is “maybe”.